# Ambiguous name detected: Worksheet_Change when adding 2 change events

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have two codes on the same sheet. One is to auto-refresh pivot, and the other is for multi-select dropdown. I have added both the codes together but the multi-select drop-down is not working. Is there any workaround for this? FYI this is how I have added the code,

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String
Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo Exitsub
If Target.Column = 18 Then

If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Exitsub
  Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Newvalue = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    Oldvalue = Target.Value
      If Oldvalue = "" Then
        Target.Value = Newvalue
      Else
        If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
            Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
      Else:
        Target.Value = Oldvalue
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True


End Sub
```

PS I also tried adding both the codes inside one private sub but none of the code is running.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String
Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo Exitsub
If Target.Column = 18 Then

If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Exitsub
  Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Newvalue = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    Oldvalue = Target.Value
      If Oldvalue = "" Then
        Target.Value = Newvalue
      Else
        If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
            Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
      Else:
        Target.Value = Oldvalue
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True


End Sub
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Ambiguous name detected: Worksheet_Change when adding 2 change events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72599360/ambiguous-name-detected-worksheet-change-when-adding-2-change-events) in SO.  You could update  your original question with the new code from your comment " both the codes within one Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range), this has removed the error but none of the code actually runs."

Comment: Also - remove the second `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` in your _PS_ code.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I tried that. The error has been resolved but the code doesn't seem to be running. Adding the code, the way you said neither update the pivots automatically nor I'm able to select multiple options from the drop down.

Comment: `On Error GoTo Exitsub` will be hiding any errors that occur.  `If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then` will cause an error if there's no validation on the sheet, but will run ok if _any_ validation is anywhere on the sheet - not specifically in the Target cell and not specifically the List validation.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure under what circumstances you want `ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll` to run.  At the moment it will run whenever you change the value in any cell.

Try this code.  `Option Explicit` and `Private OldValue As String` must be at the top of the module before any procedures.

```
Option Explicit

Private OldValue As String

'Record the old value as soon as you enter column 18.
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 18 Then
        OldValue = Target.Value
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    'Turn off events otherwise it will run again when Target value is updated.
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    
    If Target.Column = 18 Then
        'Only run if the Target cell has List type validation.
        If CellHasList(Target) Then
            Dim NewValue As String
            NewValue = Target.Value
            
            If InStr(OldValue, NewValue) = 0 Then
                Target.Value = OldValue & ", " & NewValue
            Else
                Target.Value = OldValue
            End If
        End If
    End If
    
    'Turn events back on.
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

Public Function CellHasList(cell As Range) As Boolean
    
    CellHasList = True
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim valType As Long
    valType = cell.Validation.Type 'Will return an error if no validation in Target cell.
    
    'valType = 3 is for List validation.
    If Err.Number <> 0 Or valType <> 3 Then
        CellHasList = False
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```